# passing $_POST variable with subprocess.Popen

Tags: php, python, subprocess

I have a python script which executes a php script, but I wish to pass variables:

my python:

```
cmd = ["php /mypath/myphp.php"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

my php:

```
$param1=$_POST['param1'];
$param2=$_POST['param2'];
```

How to I actually pass the arguments, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `popen` in Python and `$argv[]` in PHP

#### Python Script

```
import os

value1 = 'test'
value2 = 'test2'
cmd = rf'php /mypath/myphp.php {value1} {value2}'
os.popen(cmd)
```

#### PHP Script

```
<?php

var_dump($argv); //['myphp.php', 'test', 'test2']
echo "Value1: ".$argv[1];
echo "Value2: ".$argv[2];

?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  value1 = 'test1'
value2 = 'test2'
cmd = ["mypath/myphp.php {value1} {value2}"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: How to get or print result?